# renaming mp3 using regex

Tags: regex

I wanted to organize my mp3 files and rename them using the pattern: artist - song.

I need a regular expression that selects all the words before the first dash, and then the last dash and all characters proceeding after.

In the example, [09] System Of A Down -Toxicity - 03 - Chop Suey.mp3:

1. all the word items before the first dash: System of a down
2. the last dash: -
3. everything else after the last dash: Chop Suey.mp3

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a linux command `rename` which is exactly what you want.
For example, to rename all files matching "*.bak" to strip the extension, you might say

```
rename 's/\.bak$//' *.bak
```

To translate uppercase names to lower, you'd use

```
rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
```

To rename **[09] System Of A Down -Toxicity - 03 - Chop Suey.mp3** to **Toxicity - Chop Suey.mp3**

```
# you should rewrite regex to meet your requirement
rename 's/.*-(.*)-.*-(.*)/$1 - $2/' *.mp3
```

---

These is a Windows music player `foobar2000` which can do the job very well.
 
<kbd>Properties</kbd> -> <kbd>Format from other fields...</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, I would highly recommend using the freeware program: [MP3Tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/). It will easily do the renaming you request (and a whole lot more).

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help -

```
sed 's/[[0-9]\+] \([A-Za-z ]*[^-]\) -.*[^-]- \(.*\)/\1-\2/'
```

**Test:**

```
[jaypal:~/temp] echo "[09] System Of A Down -Toxicity - 03 - Chop Suey.mp3" | 
sed 's/[[0-9]\+] \([A-Za-z ]*[^-]\) -.*[^-]- \(.*\)/\1 - \2/'
System Of A Down - Chop Suey.mp3
```

OR

```
awk -F"-" '{print $1"-"$4}' | sed 's/[[0-9]\+] //g'
```

**Test:**

```
[jaypal:~/temp] echo "[09] System Of A Down -Toxicity - 03 - Chop Suey.mp3" | 
awk -F"-" '{print $1"-"$4}' | sed 's/[[0-9]\+] //g'
System Of A Down - Chop Suey.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the "middle pattern" by doing `(-.*-)` and replace with `-`. To remove the numbers you can use `(\[[0-9]*\])`